# Install Gnome 3 under Unity, or download Gnome distro?

Tags: gnome

My question is simple. Which one should I do?

Is there any difference between the two options?

I'd use  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit  or Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS 64 Bit

Thanks for the answers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you just install GNOME on standard Ubuntu, there will be alot of packages on the system, and it might slow it down, I did notice a speed difference between stadard Ubuntu after installing GNOME. Ubuntu GNOME has probably less packages. But I really like the Ubuntu theme that goes on stadardd Ubuntu.